# angularjs controller not working

Tags: angularjs, controller

some one please help i,m beginner and i wrote a code for the controller, when i initialize the controller in the index page it not shows the message from the script.js

```js
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello angularJS";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

please help me and guide me .... i,m beginner please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have `ng-app` defined. change `ng-app` to `ng-app="app"` in `<html>` tag

Change your `script.js` as below

```
angular.app('app', []).controller('MainController', MainController);

MainController.$inject = [$scope];

function MainController($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define ng-app name.

Use this code  html code

```
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello_world_controller.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
        <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
            <h1>{{greeting}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript code

```
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', [])
   .controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Bro it,s clear my idea about the Controller